# Dynamically duplicating a view when user hits enter in each edittext

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create an activity with a dynamic layout. The activity starts by loading a table layout with one table row that has a checkbox and an edittext. I am trying to set up the activity so that once the user has inserted some text into the edittext and hits enter on the keyboard, the same table row with a checkbox and edittext is generated below the original so that the user can create a list of items. I also want each edittext to be multiline or a max of 5 lines. I was able to get one row generated when the user hits enter but I can't figure out how to keep generating additional rows because the imeoption enter condition would somehow have to be transferred onto the next edittext that gets generated and so on instead of remaining on the original edittext. I also tried setting a lines attribute of 5 and a text attribute of textmultiline but the text remains on one line when I am testing the edittext field for some reason. I was also wondering if anyone could give me an idea on how i would store all the checkboxes and edittexts generated in an already created sql database.

Activity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_note_editor);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note_editor, null);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                    TableRow rowView = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_note, null);
                    tb.addView(rowView);
                    setContentView(tb);
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;

        }


    });


}
```

list_note_editor xml (table layout with inital row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:lines="5" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

list_view_note xml (view I want to duplicate when user hits enter on keyboard):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="5" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you may need this article [Layout Change Animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html). simply can use it on your app and animate on Activity layout with 
 `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    ...
/>`

hope to be usefull :)